# Obtener valor de variable y guardarlo en base, vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy intentando obtener el `periodoLectivoMallaOrigen= me.pAcademicoInicio + ' ' + me.cicloLectivoInicio;` que actualmente me llega lo siguiente `2222 CI` pero al enviarlo a la base de datos en la linea `periodoLectivoMallaOrigen': me.periodoLectivoMallaOrigen,` no me guarda nada.. Cual es la forma correcta de enviar el valor?

```
   enviaar(){
    var id = this.idMalla;
    let me = this;
    var arrayEstudio=[];
    var periodoLectivoMallaOrigen;
    var url= '/mallacurricular/getmalla?id=' + id;                  
    axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
        var respuesta = response.data;
        arrayEstudio = respuesta.mallaCurricular;

        me.pAcademicoInicio = arrayEstudio[0]['pAcademicoInicio'];
        me.cicloLectivoInicio = arrayEstudio[0]['cicloLectivoInicio'];
        periodoLectivoMallaOrigen= me.pAcademicoInicio + ' ' + me.cicloLectivoInicio;

    }).then(function(){
        console.log('SUCCESS ok!!');
    }).catch(function(){
        console.log('FAILURE ok!!');
    });

    axios.post('/estudioreingresomat/registrar',{     
        'idMalla': this.idMalla,
        'periodoLectivoMallaOrigen': me.periodoLectivoMallaOrigen,
        'periodoLectivoMallRediseñada': this.periodoLectivoMallRediseñada,

    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log('EXITO!!');    
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log('error al ingresar el estudio!!');
        console.log(error);
    });
 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si observas en la linea del primer response, guardas el valor en un var local

```
periodoLectivoMallaOrigen= me.pAcademicoInicio + ' ' + me.cicloLectivoInicio;
```

Cuando lo envias lo esperas desde `me` y no esta declarado allí

Puedes hacer una de las siguientes opciones

1. Corregir el primer response para que se guarde en el data de vue

```
me.periodoLectivoMallaOrigen= me.pAcademicoInicio + ' ' + me.cicloLectivoInicio;
```

2. Remover el `me` del segundo axios y que se mande la variable local que previamente ya guardaste.

```
'periodoLectivoMallaOrigen': periodoLectivoMallaOrigen,
```